# How to overcome hardware configuration limiting in detecting and pairing in bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, device-manager, wireless-keyboard

My detachable bluetooth keyboard of the Lenovo Yoga model cannot be detected by my other computer. I hold the switch in the keyboard for more then 3 seconds and the led in the keyboard blinking showing it's in pairing mode, but it isn't detected by the computer. In the Lenovo Community Forum, [a Lenovo staff says](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/2283/5120923/5543436):

> Thou the Yoga Dual's keyboard is loaded with Bluetooth 5.0, the hardware configuration might be limited in detecting and pairing with just the Yoga duel machine.

In a meta question relating to this question, [a user says](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14618/are-questions-about-the-decisions-to-limit-a-feature-on-topic?noredirect=1#comment42779_14618):

> The real reason the keyboard wouldn't work is if it was BT, one computer had a BT receiver while the other one didn't. As long as you have a compatible BT receiver the keyboard would work. Most wireless keyboards are paired to a specific receiver, sometimes they are key, that prevents the use of a different receiver even from the same make and model.

Since in Device Manager the keyboard is listed as a regular bluetooth device, I suppose there are some kind of variants of bluetooth technology, which Windows doesn't differentiate them, right?

[image]

What can I do to investigate this? Is there a way to make it work with a different computer?

Here is the [Product Specifications
Reference for Yoga Duet 7 13IML05](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Yoga/Yoga_Duet_7_13IML05/Yoga_Duet_7_13IML05_Spec.PDF), and the keyboard's info in fccid.io: [Lenovo Lenovo Duet 7 BT Folio NCC CCAK20LP0870T2](https://fccid.io/NCC/CCAK20LP0870T2)

Comment: No it doesn't seem so

Comment: The led in the keyboard blinking showing it's in pairing mode, but it isn't detected by the computer. Please check my update

Comment: Do you have a mobile phone or tablet that you could try pairing it with?

Comment: And the opposite side of @DanielB question.. Are you able to connect *other* blue-tooth devices to the computer you can't get this keyboard to connect to?